# rxjs - do something when observable starts executing

Tags: angular, rxjs

Is there a way to attach a handler when an observable starts executing (someone called subscribe on it)?

like in angular:

```
    this.http.post('someUrl', resource).pipe(
       catchError(),
       finalize((() => this.hideLoader()),
       **executing(() => this.showLoader()) <------**
    )
```

Comment: `do` might be what you're looking for? That'll just execute whatever, without modifying the stream

Comment: **do** runs when result has already emitted, i'm looking to do something when it starts executing before it emits, like in angular when an http call starts

Comment: if you place the tap operator at the beginning of the pipe, does it still occur after the source emits?

Comment: Yes, tap has already the result. (it's made to do something with the result)

Comment: Just calling `this.showLoader()` right before `this.http.post` seems like a great solution to me, why isn't that an option?

Comment: I'm returning this.http.post from a function in a service called update(), so It's not executing yet till someone calls this.service.update()

Comment: @Lerner please see if the edited answer suits you

Comment: @Ophir, yes, your answer should be a good solution, but I think that this functionality should be build into observable.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The [`defer`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-defer) observable factory function is most likely what you are looking for:

```js
import { defer } from 'rxjs';

const post = defer(() => {
  this.showLoader();
  return this.http.post('someUrl', resource).pipe(
    catchError(),
    finalize(() => this.hideLoader())
  );
});
post.subscribe();
```

Comment: @Lerner If the solution worked for you then can you accept the answer?

Comment: Is this still the answer for december 2019? Or has RXJS meanwhile a better solution? And does this solution actually create an extra observable?

Comment: `defer` is definitely the answer to the question of how to "do something like when an observable starts executing." Any operator that's not an identity creates a new observable; an operator is a function that takes an observable and returns an observable. If the before/after mechanism in this question is something that's done often, you could abstract it into a user-land operator.

Comment: What if an exception were to occur in the post() method? Wouldn't the loading indicator in that case then never go away?

Answer (score 2):

you could wrap the http.post observable in a Observable.create, and execute the logic you want there:

```
const wrapped$: Observable<any> = Observable.create((observer: 
    Observer<any>) => {
      showLoader();
       http.post('...').subscribe(
       value => observer.next(value),
       error => observer.error(error),
       () => observer.complete()
  )
});

wrapped$.subscribe() // and subscribe to this source instead
```

Comment: isn't `do` and `tap` just aliases of each other?

Comment: In situations like this, you can use `subscribe(observer)` which is considerably less verbose. (And, for this particular question, the in-built `defer` function could be used instead of `Observable.create`.)

Answer (score 2):

A bit prettier way to do the same as in previous suggestions:

```
const withLoader$ = of(null).pipe(
  tap(() => showLoader()),
  switchMap(() => this.http.post('someUrl', resource)),
  finalize(() => this.hideLoader())
);
```

Advanced sample bellow:

```
apply(observable: Observable<any>): Observable<any> {
  return of(null).pipe(
    map(() => this.show()),
    switchMap((pbKey: string) => observable.pipe(
      finalize(() => this.hide(pbKey))
    ))
  );
}
```